# How can I create a wheel where each part of the wheel is a button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a UI element that looks like an emotion wheel: [image]

I want each word to be a button that can be clicked. I want to create the shape dynamically, since I will want to change how many words are displayed based on preference.

This solution would be perfect: [Pattern of irregular clickable shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302230/pattern-of-irregular-clickable-shapes), but I am having trouble figuring out how to create the curves needed for the shape I am going for.

This post was also helpful: [How to best approximate a geometrical arc with a Bezier curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734076/how-to-best-approximate-a-geometrical-arc-with-a-bezier-curve).

Finally, I found this post: [Create a "Wheel of life" using Javascript and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087652/create-a-wheel-of-life-using-javascript-and-svg). It is very close to what I want, but each section is not its own button, and the calculation for the section and circle numbers seem to be a bit off. After testing it out it could be worth it to just figure out how to redraw the whole thing after clicking.

I am not new to software, but I am fairly new to Javascript. I feel like with enough time I could make either of these solutions work, but I want guidance on if there is a better way. I am also willing to learn more about JS frameworks, if need be. This is a personal project and I am in no rush.

Comment: I would go down the path of using an SVG with each zone on the above wheel given an ID that can be matched with an array to its description. To do this with each zone being each own button would be very difficult and would not look like the above. The last post you linked is going the right way with it but you could draw this as an SVG in something like Illustrator and add the ID's into the elements. Then add an onclick eventlistener with JS which would be able to pick up which of them have been clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the image dynamically using `<canvas>`, building each pie slice as filled paths and writing your angled text over the top.

You can discern what slices were clicked on using the click event of the canvas, mapping starting and ending degrees of each spoke, and determining the distance from the click to the center of your canvas.

```
// canvas=(your canvas element)
// e=(your click event)
let centerX = canvas.width/2;
let centerY = canvas.height/2;
let deltaX = centerX - e.clientX;
let deltaY = centerY - e.clientY;
deg = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)*180.0/Math.PI;
dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
```

If you have multiple rings of words, then `dist` could be used to determine on which ring the user clicked.  Within that ring, `deg` would determine which word was clicked on at index `(180+deg)/360`, assuming each ring represents an array of words spread evenly around the circle.